# how to add scroll bar in scatter highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created scatter graph using highchart, but not able to add vertical scroll bar when series data is in more in numbers then scoped rendering area.

Currently all series are overlapped on each other.

```
Current behavior:
https://jsfiddle.net/s1eL30Lh/235/
```

I want to add vertical scroll to chart hence all series will be displayed properly instead of overlapping on each other.

```
Some thing like: 
https://jsfiddle.net/s1eL30Lh/237/
```

Comment: Can you add the code here instead of putting jsfiddle links?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with **HighStock** not **Highcharts** - More [infos](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/)

```
yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,

    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    max: 20, // To enable a default Zoom
    title: {
      text: 'sdsdsds'
    },
},
```

[Api Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.scrollbar) and [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/s1eL30Lh/251/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and this is exactly what i needed, but if you see the chart, scroll is not working and series are overlapped on each other.

Comment: @mohdammarraza, you can set the default zoom with `max:20`. I updated the fiddle.

Comment: @mohdammarraza, you're welcome. I see you're new to SO. If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase the height of the `div` in which you are populating the graph.

`<div id="container" style="height: 800px;""></div>`

```js
function toMs(h, m) {
  return Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, h, m);
}

var series = [{
  // First series
  name: 'Running',
  color: 'green',
  dataRaw: [{
    y: 1,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 30), toMs(15, 40)],
      [toMs(15, 50), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 2,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 30), toMs(15, 55)]
    ]
  }]
}, {
  // Second series
  name: 'Not running',
  color: 'red',
  dataRaw: [{
    y: 1,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 40), toMs(15, 50)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 2,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 3,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 4,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 5,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 2,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 2,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 6,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 7,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 8,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 9,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 10,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 11,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 12,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 13,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 14,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 15,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 16,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }, {
    y: 17,
    xRanges: [
      // first value: from; second value: to
      [toMs(15, 55), toMs(16, 10)]
    ]
  }]
}].map(function(series) {
  series.data = [];
  series.dataRaw.forEach(function(dataRaw) {
    dataRaw.xRanges.forEach(function(xRange) {
      series.data.push([xRange[0], dataRaw.y], [xRange[1], dataRaw.y], [xRange[1], null]); // null breakes the line
    }); // forEach
  }); // forEach
  return series;
});


var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    height:500,
  //width: 300,
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Example'
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.x);
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      lineWidth: 5,
      marker: {
        enabled: false,
        symbol: 'circle'
      }
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Time'
    },
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute
      second: '%H:%M',
      minute: '%H:%M',
      hour: '%H:%M',
      day: '%H:%M',
      week: '%H:%M',
      month: '%H:%M',
      year: '%H:%M'
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    
  },

  yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    title: {
       text: 'sdsdsds'
    },
  },
  series: series
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 800px;""></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually i want to add scroll bar in chart itself. increasing div height will increase div size.